# Croogo vs CakePHP post edit issue

Tags: post, cakephp, edit, croogo

I have a CakePHP app setup with CakePHP version 3.5 and Croogo version 3.0.x-dev. I am having an issue with content insert and edit. Ex: blog post.

If I save any content ex: /admin/nodes/nodes/add/blog with "Publish on" and "Un-publish on" field values (Selecting date by the datepicker) then when I go to edit that post I am getting error "Call to a member function format() on null
Cake\Error\FatalErrorException"

But If I save any content keeping those fields "Publish on" and "Un-publish on" empty. Then when I go to edit that post IT WORKS!

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed with updated croogo version to 3.0.5.